# Do groups have Duals?

Tags: group-theory, duality-theorems, dual-spaces

Do groups have Duals?

Might be a bit of a simple question but it should not take too much effort to handle. Notice that I'm not saying all or automatically or anything like that.

I'm merely wondering whether on the level of group and group theory Duals are something you discuss.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin_duality.

Comment: Characters of abelian groups generalize to nonabelian groups using representation theory (they are no longer homomorphisms though).

Answer (score 11):

There are a few things claiming to be the dual of a group!

The [**Pontryagin dual**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin_duality#The_dual_group) of a locally compact abelian group $G$ is the group of continuous group homomorphisms from $G$ to the multiplicative group of complex numbers with norm $1$, that is, the unit circle in the complex plane. This satisfies the desired property that the dual of the dual is canonically isomorphic to the original group, just as in the vector space case. The Pontryagin dual is used extensively in harmonic analysis, and elsewhere.

The [**Langlands dual**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langlands_dual_group) is a substantially more complicated object; the groups it applies to are the *reductive algebraic* groups, and the definition of "reductive algebraic" is [a bit technical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductive_group). In the Langlands program, the functoriality principle states roughly that a homomorphism between the Langlands duals of two groups should give you a way to transfer a "nice" representation of one to a "nice" representation of the other (I'm not going to try to define this more precisely, since I don't *understand* it more precisely). Revealing my ignorance, **I can't tell you what this is good for** - the Langlands program is quite technical, and I don't have a good understanding of what kinds of consequences it has or why the Langlands dual construction is the right construction to get at those consequences. But hopefully someone more knowledgeable than me can chime in.

I believe there are other notions of dual, but these are the two that I've heard of (and the Pontryagin dual is the one I understand).

Comment: Without going into too much detail: To get the Langlands' dual $G^\vee$ of a group $G$, you swap characters for cocharacters, roots for coroots and center for the fundamental group. On the level of the Lie algebra "almost" nothing happens except type $B_n$ becomes type $C_n$. One way Langlands' duality is useful comes from "Satake correspondence" which gives you and isomorphism between the ring of characters of $G$ (treated as a complex Lie group) and the ring of certain biinvariant functions on $G^\vee(K)$, where $K$ is a certain field with discrete valuation.

Comment: ...This isomorphism allows you to relate the representation theory on one side and the geometry on the Langlands' dual side. The Kazhdan-Lustig polynomials show up as matrix coefficients of the Satake correspondence.

Answer (score 6):

Classically, for a group $G$, the dual group of $G$ is defined as $Hom(G, \mu)$, the group of homomorphisms from $G$ to $\mu$ where $\mu$ is the multiplicative group of roots of unity in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: do you have any sources?

Comment: _Abstract Algebra_ Dummit et Foote

Comment: Do you mean the set of all complex numbers with norm $1$? E.g $e^{i}$ isn't an $n$th-root of unity for any $n$, but it is on the unit circle.

Comment: Thats a 1000 page book....

Comment: Not the full unit circle, only those being roots of unity: i.e. of the form $e^{\frac{2\pi i k}{n}$ for any $k,n \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo chap 5 pg 168

Comment: oh yeah, 167 in my copy. Nice

Comment: @user253929 Huh, that's different from the Pontryagin dual - I haven't seen that definition before! Does this thing have a name more specific than "dual" (to distinguish it especially from the Pontryagin dual)?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I have only ever seen this listed plainly as dual group which is unfortunate. I also recall in Hatcher _Algebraic Topology_ cochain complexes $C^n$ briefly referred to as THE "dual group" of $C_n$ where we have already a group $G$ of coefficients and $C^n = Hom(C_n,G)$

Comment: do you know of any desirable properties this thing has to merit it being called the dual group?

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo As for why it bares the name, for an object $X$ the group of morphisms $Hom(X,Y)$ for some $Y$ in the same category as $X$ is denoted as the dual object. And this definition doesn't call for a particular $Y$. As to why this definition of dual group warrants the name over Pontryagin dual, I am unsure, a cursory observation is for finite $G$ the definition yields isomorphic results, no?

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo Also this definition does not require $G$ abelian

Answer (score 1):

Let the set $G$ be a group under the operation $\ast.$ The *opposite* group is the set $G$ with the opposite operation $\circ$ defined by $a\circ b = b\ast a.$ Note that abelian groups are their own opposites.

Obviously, the opposite of the opposite is the original group, so this is a kind of dual operation.

For more, see Mac Lane and Birkhoff, *Algebra*.

Comment: This isn't the analogue of the dual of a vector space in any way, though, so I don't think it really should be called a "dual."

Comment: Would it be better as a comment?

Comment: *Every* group is isomorphic to its own opposite in this sense: the isomorphism is $g \mapsto g^{-1}$

Comment: In particular, this construction is covariant.